# When using both @keyframes and @-webkit-keyframes, should I provide with the -webkit-transform & transform in both animations?

Tags: html, css

Example code provided,

I would like to know how much of it is redundant.

```html
<style>
.wobble {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #777;
}
.wobble:hover {
  animation-name: wobble;
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;

  -webkit-animation-name: wobble;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wobble {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
  15% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -5deg);
    transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -5deg);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(20%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 3deg);
    transform: translate3d(20%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 3deg);
  }
  45% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-15%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
    transform: translate3d(-15%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 2deg);
    transform: translate3d(10%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 2deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-5%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -1deg);
    transform: translate3d(-5%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -1deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

@keyframes wobble {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
  15% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -5deg);
    transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -5deg);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(20%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 3deg);
    transform: translate3d(20%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 3deg);
  }
  45% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-15%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
    transform: translate3d(-15%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 2deg);
    transform: translate3d(10%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 2deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-5%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -1deg);
    transform: translate3d(-5%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -1deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
</style>


<div class="wobble">Wobble</div>
```